# python __getattribute__ override and @property decorator

Tags: python, class, attributes

I had to write a class of some sort that overrides `__getattribute__`. 
basically my class is a container, which saves every user-added property to `self._meta` which is a dictionary.

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__setattr__('_meta', OrderedDict())
        #self._meta = OrderedDict()
        super(Container, self).__setattr__('_hasattr', lambda key : key in self._meta)

        for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            self._meta[attr] = value

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        try:
            return super(Container, self).__getattribute__(key)
        except:
            if key in self._meta : return self._meta[key]
            else:
                raise AttributeError, key

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self._meta[key] = value
#usage:
>>> a = Container()
>>> a
<__main__.Container object at 0x0000000002B2DA58>
>>> a.abc = 1 #set an attribute
>>> a._meta
OrderedDict([('abc', 1)]) #attribute is in ._meta dictionary
```

I have some classes which inherit `Container` base class and some of their methods have @property decorator.

```
class Response(Container):
    @property
    def rawtext(self):
        if self._hasattr("value") and self.value is not None:
            _raw = self.__repr__()
            _raw += "|%s" %(self.value.encode("utf-8"))

            return _raw
```

problem is that `.rawtext` isn't accessible. (I get attributeerror.) every key in `._meta` is accessible, every attributes added by `__setattr__` of `object` base class is accessible, but method-to-properties by @property decorator isn't. I think it has to do with my way of overriding `__getattribute__` in `Container` base class. What should I do to make properties from `@property` accessible?

Comment: Do you actually *need* to use `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`?

Comment: @mgilson How can I do with `__getattr__`?

Comment: `__getattr__` is called only if the attribute is not found on the instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should probably think about looking at [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) instead of [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) here.  The difference is this:  `__getattribute__` is called inconditionally if it exists -- `__getattr__` is only called if python can't find the attribute via other means.

Comment: I see, so I should not touch `__getattribute__` and modify only `__getattr__` to let python protocol do the job?

Comment: @thkang -- that's what I'm proposing, yes :).  with your `__setattr__` the way it is, it should do the right thing I think. (i.e, It should pack attributes into the meta ordered dict, but will still allow properties and methods! on subclasses)

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with mgilson. If you want a sample code which should be equivalent to your code but work well with properties you can try:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._meta = OrderedDict()
        #self._hasattr = lambda key: key in self._meta  #???
        for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            self._meta[attr] = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._meta[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in ('_meta', '_hasattr'):
            super(Container, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            self._meta[key] = value
```

I really do not understand your `_hasattr` attribute. You put it as an attribute but it's actually a function that has access to `self`... shouldn't it be a method?
Actually I think you should simple use the built-in function `hasattr`:

```
class Response(Container):
    @property
    def rawtext(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'value') and self.value is not None:
            _raw = self.__repr__()
            _raw += "|%s" %(self.value.encode("utf-8"))

            return _raw
```

Note that `hasattr(container, attr)` will return `True` also for `_meta`.

An other thing that puzzles me is why you use an `OrderedDict`. I mean, you iterate over `kwargs`, and the iteration has random order since it's a normal `dict`, and add the items in the `OrderedDict`. Now you have `_meta` which contains the values in random order.
If you aren't sure whether you need to have a specific order or not, simply use `dict` and eventually swap to `OrderedDict` later.

By the way: never *ever* use an `try: ... except:` without specifying the exception to catch. In your code you actually wanted to catch only `AttributeError`s so you should have done:

```
try:
    return super(Container, self).__getattribute__(key)
except AttributeError:
    #stuff
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. I see your point with kwargs - I was missing something critical there. No need for kwargs as you said :D

Comment: Question - how would one implement a delete method here?