# Implement _del_ method for a class with __getattribute__ overriden

Tags: python, class, attributes, metaclass

Taking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689836/python-getattribute-override-and-property-decorator%20%22) as a pointer, let's say there exists a class like the following:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self._meta = defaultdict(lambda: None)
      for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
          self._meta[attr] = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
      try:
          return self._meta[key]
      except KeyError:
          raise AttributeError(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
      if key in ('_meta', '_hasattr'):
          super(Container, self).__setattr__(key, value)
      else:
          self._meta[key] = value
```

This allows the following behavior:

```
c = Container()
c.a = 1
print(c.a) # 1
print(c.b) # None
```

**Question**: What is the best way to implement an operator such that the following works:

```
# Should delete the value of a from Container._meta
del c.a
```

Of course, one could obviously implement a method like,

```
def _delete(self, key):
  ...
```

But is there way to re-use a python operator to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `__delattr__` method:

```
def __delattr__(self, key):
    del self._meta[key]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried this before, and for some reason it wasn't working. I think the reason was that I was doing a "if key in self._meta", which screwed it up in some way I haven't been able to figure out yet.