# Python - When to use ()

Tags: python, class, methods

Folks,

After much searching and reading I have come to the conclusion that methods use () and attributes don't.

Example using `arr=np.arrange(25)`:

To find the size of the array I'd use: `arr.size` This is an attribute.

To find the max of the array I'd use: `arr.max()` This is a method.

To me, as an amateur python coder, I can't for the life of me tell what the actual difference is. *(Note: I do understand that an attribute is found under _ _init_ _ while methods are not.)* Is it really just the person who wrote the class randomly decided to put size as an attribute and max as method? Is there any way to tell while writing code to intuitively know when to use () and when not to without looking up the list of methods and attributes for each class?

Thanks for the help and sorry if I have any of the terms incorrect.

Comment: It isn't always simple to decide and subject to discussion but a method should be used if (1) one or more parameters are or may be needed (e.g. the `np.arange(...)`, (2) a new object is created by the call (e.g. `list.copy()`), (3) the object is modified by the call (e.g. `list.sort()`), (4) a complicated or long-running calculation is started by the call (also `list.sort()`)

Comment: you may use attribute, if the intend is just to save data. you may use function, if you intend to perform certain operation (now or in future). getters and setters transform attribute behave like function.

Answer (score 1):

The full story is a little complicated (for all of it, see [Python: the __getattribute__ method and descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24863787/1256452) and [python __getattribute__ override and @property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14689836/1256452) and follow the links to the [wiki on descriptor protocols](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod)), but in short, you write:

```
somevar.thing()
```

when you want to *call* the `thing`, and you write:

```
somevar.thing
```

when you want to *use the value of* the `thing`.  This usage is the same as with functions and non-functions:

```
def f(arg):
    print('f called, arg =', arg)
    return 42

x = f('douglas adams')
print('f returned', x)

y = x
print('I just set y to x:', y)

y = f
print('this time I did not call', y)
```

which, when run (as Python3 or with `from __future__ import print_function` in Python2) prints:

```
f called, arg = douglas adams
f returned 42
I just set y to x: 42
this time I did not call <function f at ...>
```

If we try to do `y = x()`, it fails because we cannot *call* `42`.

If you are going to define how the `thing` is to be used, define it as a method if it needs to be *called*, and as an instance attribute if it's just to be *used* (and/or set to some value).  If you make the wrong decision—if you make it a used/set instance attribute, and it turns out later you need a function—you can work around it later with `@property`.

---

What's special about instance methods is that when you call them—or even when you don't—you get an extra `self` argument.  The implementation by which this occurs is different in Python2 and Python3, but:

```
class K(object):
    def method(self, arg):
        print('method called, arg is', arg)

x = K()
x.method(42)
```

prints:

```
method called, arg is 42
```

Note that if we *don't* call it, we see this as a "bound method":

```
print('x.method is', x.method)
```

produces:

```
x.method is <bound method K.method of <__main__.K object at ...>>
```

If we look at `K.method` directly, the difference between Python2 and Python3 shows up:

```
$ python2 x.py
K.method is <unbound method K.method>
$ python3.6 x.py
K.method is <function K.method at ...>
```

but in the end it's all just descriptor protocols, with [the CPython implementation able to do some short-cutting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24863898/1256452).